# Visual studio code can't run python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have downloaded Visual Studio code and Python. I want to run my python file. When I do it from the terminal in VSCode everything is fine (I write python .\file.py).

However when I try to do it by clicking run or Ctrl + F5 it says:

C:\Users\Lastname Lastname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'd:\\MYNAME\\MYFOLDER\\Studies\\5term\\Subject\\lab1\\Report1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I tried to remove my file from disk D to C or remove Polish characters (I am Polish) from the path but it didn't improve my situation.

I still doesn't understand why it can find a file it has just opened and I am 100% sure exist. It seems it can't find itself!

Also why does it duplicate the '\' character why describing path?

Comment: There are spaces in your username, which may be the problem. Switch to a directory with no spaces, no special characters, and an all-English directory.

Comment: You are 100% convinced that file exists at exactly the path in the error?  Because I'm pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are spaces in your username. You can modify your script path according to the following requirements.

- Full English
- no spaces
- no special characters

Comment: That's clearly not the problem.  The error is complaining about Report1.py, not python.exe.